# Accessing `goog.require`d object in closure library without compilation

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library

I'm experimenting with the google closure library, and am working through [the
official XhrIo guide](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/xhrio).
I ran into some trouble with the `xhr-quick2.js` example, reproduced below:

```
goog.require('goog.net.XhrIo');

var xhr = new goog.net.XhrIo();

goog.events.listen(xhr, goog.net.EventType.COMPLETE, function(e) {
  obj = this.getResponseJson();
  log('Received Json data object with title property of "' +  
      obj['title'] + '"'); 
  alert(obj['content']);
});

function getData(dataUrl) {
  log('Sending simple request for ['+ dataUrl + ']');
  xhr.send(dataUrl);
}
```

When run, I receive the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'XhrIo' of undefined

If I move the event listener and xhr instantiation to within the `getData`
function (which is called in the body's `onload`), all is well.

```
goog.require('goog.net.XhrIo')

function getData(dataUrl) {
  var xhr = new goog.net.XhrIo()

  goog.events.listen(xhr, goog.net.EventType.COMPLETE, function(e) {
    obj = this.getResponseJson()
    log(`Received Json data object with title property of "${ obj["title"] }"`)
    alert(obj["content"])
  })

  log(`Sending simple request for [${ dataUrl }]`)
  xhr.send(dataUrl)
}

function log(msg) {
  document.getElementById('log').appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
  document.getElementById('log').appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
}
```

I assume this is because `goog.require` hasn't finished importing `net` when
`goog.net.XhrIo` is instantiated on line 3 of the first code sample. I suppose
the ideal solution is to run all my code through the closure compiler, but I'm
just experimenting and [other parts of the
documentation](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/gettingstarted)
imply my workflow is acceptable for development.

Is there anything I can manually source in my html that would eliminate this
problem? Is there some other approach I should take?

Answer (score 2):

It's been a few years since I last played with closure, but I don't think you can just use require without the dependency compiler.

Closure works by scanning your JavaScript files for `goog.module` and `goog.require` to write a `deps.js` file. This file has to be loaded first before your JavaScript files. It lists all the modules used by the code and loads them in the correct order.

If `deps.js` comes first, then `goog.net` will be loaded in by the time it gets to your code. The code `goog.require('goog.net.XhrIo')` on line 1 will at this time be ignored.

According to the docs the `goog.require` will insert a `<script>` tag *after* the current `<script>` being executed. So if you want to skip the step of using `deps.js` then you'll have to wrap everything in a document ready callback, or manaully add `goog.require` to a JavaScript file that is loaded before your code.

I think it's not worth the effort and easier to just use the closure dependency writer to create the `deps.js` file.

There's a quick tutorial here:

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/closure-the-definitive/9781449381882/ch01.html

Here's the CLI for writing the `deps.js` file:

```
python ../closure-library/closure/bin/calcdeps.py \
    --dep ../closure-library \
    --path my_stuff.js \
    --output_mode deps > deps.js
```

Answer (score 0):

For uncompiled mode, the required document must be pre-loaded. So in your html document you would have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="path/to/closure/base.js"></script>
    <script>
      goog.require('goog.net.XhrIo');
    </script>
    <script src="mysource.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Any dependencies must be loaded in a separate script tag. Then your code samples above should work.